# react native Task :expo-av:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I shifted to M1 machine and getting this error for `expo-av`, I couldn't find anything related to this error, it is happening only in android...

Command used to run project: `npx react-native run-android`
Build Error:

```
> Task :expo-av:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-av:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1405] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake''

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

Package.json

```
"expo": "^46.0.0",
"expo-av": "~12.0.4",
"react-native": "0.69.6",
```

Output of `npx react-native info`:

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 12.5
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 227.61 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 19.0.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.24.2 - ~/Desktop/project/node_modules/.bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29, 30, 31, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
    react-native: 0.69.6 => 0.69.6 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

It might be a gradle problem? I'm not sure...

Android Studio config:

```
SDK Platforms
  Android Tiramisu (Tiramisu)
    -> Android SDK Platform 33 (installed)
    -> Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (installed)
    -> Google Play ARM 64 v8a System Image (installed)
  Android 12.0 (S)
    -> Android SDK Platform 31 (installed) // as per my project's build.gradle
    -> Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (installed)
    -> Google Play ARM 64 v8a System Image (installed)
  Android 11.0 (R)
    -> Android SDK Platform 30 (installed)
  Android 10.0 (Q)
    -> Android SDK Platform 29 (installed)

SDK Tools
  -> 33.0.0 (installed)
  -> 31.0.0 (installed)
  -> 30.0.3 (installed)
  NDK (side by side)
    -> 21.4.7075529 (installed)
    -> 24.0.8215888 (installed) // as per my project's build.gradle
  Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
    -> Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)  8.0 (installed)
  CMake
    -> 3.22.1  (installed)
    -> 3.18.1  (installed)
  Android Emulator  31.3.13 (installed)
  Android SDK Platform-Tools   33.0.3 (installed)
```

I tried: `cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android` but not luck...

**UPDATE - 1**:

I was able to reproduce the exact same build error using the following steps and I have also shared a reproducible repo: https://github.com/theartificialguy/rn-m1

```
1) on an M1 MacBook -> npx react-native init m1project --version 0.69.6
2) npx react-native run-android -> It was working.
3) npx install-expo-modules@latest
4) npx expo install expo-av
5) npx react-native run-android -> Got the same build error as mentioned in the title.
```

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

If anyone need more info I can provide, just ask what you need...

Comment: coming from discord here! brother can you try downgrading expo-av !   as you are not using the latest RN either! 

i think so expo-av latest version is not supporting the current SDK 

i will say use expo sdk of 46 ! that will help. i also using the same

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> CMake
uncheck the check options and install it again and try to build it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dont update manually expo

get the previous expo version and install that version .