# react native android studio build failed

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile, expo

I had a project at react-native expo, I did a prebuild and tried to run it in android studio after installing all the dependencies for android studio, but it gives an error when building

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-av:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\New2\Desktop\lfl_android\lfl-test\node_modules\expo-av\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\New2\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
        "-HC:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android" ^
        "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
        "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
        "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21" ^
        "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21" ^
        "-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\New2\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
        "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\New2\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
        "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Users\\New2\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
        "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\\Users\\New2\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all" ^
        "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\5tc36e28\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\5tc36e28\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
        "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=C:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\5tc36e28\\prefab\\arm64-v8a\\prefab" ^
        "-BC:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\5tc36e28\\arm64-v8a" ^
        -GNinja ^
        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" ^
        "-DREACT_NATIVE_DIR=C:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\react-native" ^
        "-DRN_SO_DIR=C:\\Users\\New2\\Desktop\\lfl_android\\lfl-test\\node_modules\\expo-av\\android\\build/react/jni"
    from C:\Users\New2\Desktop\lfl_android\lfl-test\node_modules\expo-av\android

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

I've already tried everything, changing devices, SDK, deleting the build, clearing the cache, deleting dependencies

P.S. I tried unchecking CMAKE, today I tried to create a project on React Native and on React Native Expo, without Expo a clean project on Expo is launched, it displays the same error

Comment: have you tried: Open Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> CMake
uncheck the check options and install it again and try to build it again as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497904/react-native-task-expo-avconfigurecmakedebugarm64-v8a-failed